# Flash Media Server admin API connection reset

Tags: flash, flash-media-server

I'm trying to get server stats off the FMS admin API like this:

http://example.com:1111/admin/getIOStats?auser=XXX&apswd=YYY

I have API commands enabled in the Users.xml config.

When I use a bad user name or password, I get an XML error response, as expected.

When I use a correct user name or password, I get a "Connection reset" error ("The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.")

My security group on EC2 should be correct, because that URL works fine on a dev FMS box in the same security group.

I looked at the Apache logs and the FMS logs and don't see any trace of my admin requests, so I must be looking in the wrong place.

So, three questions:

1. What's serving the admin API over :1111? Apache?
2. Where are the admin API access and error logs?
3. What's causing my connection reset errors?

Answer (score 1):

For reference in case people run into the same problem: the connection reset errors are because you need to enable API access over http in three different places.

If your conf/fms.ini file is mostly default, be sure to include this:

```
    USERS.HTTPCOMMAND_ALLOW = true
```

Then in in conf/Users.xml, include this:

```
    <AdminServer>
        <HTTPCommands>
            <Enable>${USERS.HTTPCOMMAND_ALLOW}</Enable>
            <Allow>ping,getXXXStats</Allow>
            <Order>Allow,Deny</Order>
        </HTTPCommands>
    </AdminServer>
```

In summary:

- turn http API access on or off with `USERS.HTTPCOMMENT_ALLOW = true` in fms.ini
- make sure the `<Enable>` section in Users.xml includes that value
- list exactly which API calls you allow in `<Allow>`

If the `<Enable>` section is not set to true, you'll get the connection reset error (instead of something more sensible like a 500 or a 403).